# UITableViewCell has extra spacing on left and right in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I've already used the following code to fix the separator issue:

```
if([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
      [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

However in iOS7 there is still a larger gap between the left and right edges of the `UITableView` and the `cell.textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`

I have custom UITableViewCells where I specify a position for a text label so this causes misalignment of the labels with the standard cells in either iOS 6 and 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to provide a screenshot?

Comment: How about creating your own custom cell? Not too much work IMHO.

Comment: It will work fine if u use it via xcode 4.X. Its issue with Xcode 5. And there is no way out. You will have to conditionally compile code for ios6 and ios7 separately using custom cells.

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution which will remain consistent on ios 6,7

 and you can put custom `UILabel` and connect to custom `UITableViewCell` class.

[image: Cell Divider]

You can set divider by putting an UIImageView at the bottom edge of cell

 and set Separator style to none from storyboard.

[image: Set separator to None]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboard? If you are, it is best to do that from the storyboard. Select your UITableView Object from the UIViewController in the storyboard. Under "Attributes Inspector", find "Separator Inset", select "Custom" and make sure "Left" and "Right" are both 0.

Screen Shot:-

[image: UITableView Separator Inset]

Answer (score 0):

For UITableViewCell, the cell.textLabel and detailTextLabel's frame can only be modified in subclass of UITableViewCell. Just try this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = self.textLbFrame;
   self.detailTextLbFrame = self.detailTextLabel.frame; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are options when configuring the constraints in the Storyboard to make the constraint *relative to margin*. That option seems to be selected by default in the case of tableviews.

**To fix:** Select each horizontal constraint, select the `Superview.Leading / Trailing` and uncheck the `Relative to margin`.

[image]

[image]